# Background App Image and partially transparent custom action bar

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, imageview, android-styles

I'm new in Android. 
I have two questions:

I have an application with a first Login view and some others view.

I would like to set an image as background for all views except the login view. Is there a way to set this background view in some way or do I need to have an ImageView into every layouts?

Is it possible to have the action bar partially transparent? I would like to overlap the action bar on the background image into every view.

Is possible to have an ActionBar with customized height? I would like to have an action bar thinner but not completely on top (I would not want it to start from y = 0) Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

For background image, you can set your default app theme with a background.
/res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_orange</item>
</style>
```

You can set your default theme for the whole application in AndroidManifest file with application tag.

Then you create another style for login activity and set the theme from AndroidManifest > activity tag for login.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

For ActionBar I'm not sure you can change the height, you may need to use a custom action bar implementation for that.

You may want to check this resources for custom action bar implementations, 
[Custom actionbar layout with overflow menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353489/custom-actionbar-layout-with-overflow-menu)
[Android ActionBar custom layout styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20972324/android-actionbar-custom-layout-styling)
[How can I implement custom Action Bar with custom buttons in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518414/how-can-i-implement-custom-action-bar-with-custom-buttons-in-android)

You can change the style of ActionBar, you can give a background color with alpha and use windowActionBarOverlay property for the Action Bar style.
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html
 
[Transparent Actionbar: custom tabcolor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726214/transparent-actionbar-custom-tabcolor)

Comment: Also this might be helpful for styling Action Bar,
[http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/)