# Toolbar's popup menu - custom background (color and borders)

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-theme, android-styles, android-menu

How can I make such popup item menu for my toolbar (support v7)?

[screenshot of transparent toolbar's popup menu (MX Player)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeZMr.png)

I found out how to make transparent background:

**from layout**

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:theme="@style/MyToolbarTheme"/>
```

**from style**

```
  <style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/my_transparent_color</item>
  </style>
```

but how to add borders?

p.s. using shape `android:background` will cause a lot of shapes everywhere

```
<item name="android:background">@drawable/background_with_borders</item>
```

Comment: checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353489/custom-actionbar-layout-with-overflow-menu

Comment: @Sahil nothing to check there